# Define a constant dictionary Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using Objective-C, I have a dictionary of 30 entry, I am trying to define it in my Constants file the same way I am defining `String` or `Int`:

```
define key @"value"
```

Is it possible to define a dictionary in this way? 
If yes, what's the syntax to define an Array?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use shorthand syntax: `@{@"key":@"value"}` or `@[@"item1"]` and you can put them into #define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define whatever you want. If you write

```
#define identifier replacement
```

Preprocessor during compilation (actually before he compiles anything) looks for `indentifier` in your source code and replaces it with `replacement`.

You can define your dictionary or array in this way

```
#define kDictionary @{"key" : "value"\
                      "key2" : "value2"}
#define kArray @["item1", "item2"]
```

Backslash at the end of line is required for multiline defines.

However I don't recommend to use `#define`. You should rather create class with class method that will provide you with the dictionary/array. It is less error prone.